# How to render Positive, Negative differences as area between two lines in eCharts?

Tags: javascript, visualization, echarts

If we have two line charts, comparing say My Portfolio vs Overall Portfolio, the area between two lines need to be highlighted as green where My Portfolio is more than Overall portfolio, and red where it is less.

This is the kind of output that is expected -
[image]

```js
var chartDom = document.getElementById('profileAumChart');
var myChart = echarts.init(chartDom);
var option;

option = {
title: {
    show: false
},
tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis'
},
legend: {
    data: ['My Portfolio', 'Overall Portfolio']
},
grid: {
    left: '3%',
    right: '4%',
    bottom: '3%',
    containLabel: true
},
toolbox: {
    show: false
},
xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    boundaryGap: false,
    data: ['Jan-21','Feb-21','Mar-21','Apr-21','May-21', 'Jun-21', 'Jul-21', 'Aug-21', 'Sep-21', 'Oct-21', 'Nov-21', 'Dec-21']
},
yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
},
series: [
    {
        name: 'My Portfolio',
        type: 'line',
        areaStyle: {
            color: 'green',
            //opacity: 1,
        },

        data: [150100,175965,185385,201384,206279,235905,238021,239323,245282,247671,255447,275911],
    },
    {

        name: 'Overall Portfolio',
        type: 'line',
        areaStyle: {
            color:'red',

            //opacity:1
        },

        data: [155066,165142,190811,192906,231941,250216,270047,288033,291842,308232,320941,334013],
    }
]
};

option && myChart.setOption(option);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.3.0/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
<div id="profileAumChart" style="width:100%; height:270px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to replicate the effect with an hack. I added a hidden series which has the lowest of the two series, and use the attribute "areastyle" and their sub-attribute color and opacity along with z-index and I am able to show such region.

I am still looking for an elegant solution and in case someone post it would really appreciate it.

I am sharing my code which can help someone who intend to have similar effects using e-charts.

Thanks.

```js
var chartDom = document.getElementById('profileMonthlyNetSales');
            var myChart = echarts.init(chartDom);
            var option;

            option = {
            title: {
                show: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                trigger: 'axis'
            },
            legend: {
                data: ['My Portfolio', 'Overall Portfolio'],
                left: 'left'
            },
            grid: {
                left: '3%',
                right: '4%',
                bottom: '3%',
                containLabel: true
            },
            toolbox: {
                show: false
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'category',
                boundaryGap: false,
                axisLabel:{
                    margin: 20,
                },
                data: ['Jan-21','Feb-21','Mar-21','Apr-21','May-21', 'Jun-21', 'Jul-21', 'Aug-21', 'Sep-21', 'Oct-21', 'Nov-21', 'Dec-21']
            },
            yAxis: [{
                type: 'value',
                min: -15000,
                offset: 10,
                axisLabel: {
                    //formatter: '${value}M'
                    formatter: function (value, index) {
                        return '$' + (value/1000) + 'k';
                    }
                }
            }
            ],
            series: [
                {
                    z:-1,
                    name: 'My Portfolio',
                    type: 'line',
                    
                    areaStyle: {
                        color: 'green',
                        opacity:0.25,
                        origin: "start",
                        
                    },
                    symbolSize: 5,
                    emphasis:{
                        disabled:true
                    },
                    data: [-6000,-1000,-7500,-7500,15300,16000,4900,5000,800, -9800, -10000, -9000],
                },
                {
                    z:-1,
                    name: 'Overall Portfolio',
                    type: 'line',
                    color: "#808080",
                    areaStyle: {
                        color:'red',
                        opacity: 0.25,
                        origin: "start",
                    },
                    symbolSize: 5,
                    emphasis:{
                        disabled:true
                    },
                    data: [-3000,-4000,-3700,-5000,15000,14800,5000,10200,5000,-9800,-1000,-8000],
                },
                {
                    z:-1,
                    name: 'Overall Portfolio1',
                    tooltip: {
                        show: false
                    },
                    type: 'line',
                    areaStyle: {
                        color:"white",
                        opacity:1.0, 
                        origin: "start",
                    },
                    lineStyle: {
                        opacity: 0,
                    },
                    emphasis:{
                        disabled:true
                    },
                    symbolSize: 0,
                    data: [-6000,-4000,-7500,-7500,15000,14800,4900,5000,800,-9800,-10000,-9000],
                }
            ],
            
            };

            option && myChart.setOption(option);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.3.0/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
<div id="profileMonthlyNetSales" style="width:100%; height:270px;"></div>
```

Comment: That's a nice idea, but this only works if the line intersections are all at the data points (at least that's for my scenario, where I'm trying to fill the color up from the x-axis line). I'm going to end up calculating the intersects from my data, and creating extra points there... which also seems like a hacky workaround but at least it'll work. It would be great if eCharts supported some sort of clipping mask method for this.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing something similar to what @Amit Pandey did, but with stacked area charts.

https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=area-stack

You find the minimum of the 2 points, and render that as the bottom line/area, then you stack another area chart on top of that bottom line (this values for this stacked chart is the difference between the minimum values and the 'actual' chart value). You can then change the colour of the stacked chart to whatever you want and you can visualize that difference.

This still doesn't solve the issue of line intersects - so if you really want it to look good, you still have to calculate the intersections and add those points in - I ended up using [mathjs](https://mathjs.org/)' intersect function to do this.